# Deploy hyperledger on AWS - production setup

Tags: amazon-web-services, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

My company is currently evaluating hyperledger(fabric) and we're using it for our POC. It looks very promising and we're targeting rolling out to production in next few months.

We're targeting AWS as our production environment.

However, we're struggling to find good tutorial/practices/recommendations about operating hyperledger network in such environment.

I'm aware that Cello is aiming to solve/ease deploying/monitoring hyperledger network but i also read that its not production ready yet. Question is, should we even consider looking at Cello at this point?

If not, what are our alternatives? Docker swarm, kubernetes?

I also didn't find information about recommended instance types. I understand this is application and AWS specific but what are the minimal system requirements
(memory&CPU&network) for example for 'peer' node (our application is not network intensive, nor a lot of transactions will be submitted per hour/day, only few of them per day).

Another question is where to create those instances on AWS from geographical&decentralization point of view. Does it make sense all of them to be created in same region? Or, we must create instances running in different regions?

Tnx a lot.
Igor.

Answer (score 2):

yes, look at Cello.. if nothing else it will help you see the aws deployment model.

really nothing special..

design the desired system, peers, orderer, gateways, etc..
then decide who many ec2 instance u need to support that.

as for WHERE (region).. depends on where the connecting application is and what kind of fault tolerance you need for your business model.

one of the businesses I am working with wants a minimum of 99.99999 % availability.   so, multi-region is critical. its just another ec2 instance with sockets open from different hosts..

Answer (score 0):

aws doesn't provide much in terms of support for hyperledger. they have some templates which allow you to setup the VMs initially, but that's stuff you can do yourself as well.

you are right, the documentation is very light and most of the time confusing. I got to the point where I can start from scratch with a brand new VM and got everything ready and deploy my own network definition and chaincode and have the scripts to do that.

IBM cloud has much better support for hyperledger however. you can design your network visually, you can download your connection profiles, deploy and instantiate chaincode, create and join channels, handle certificates, pretty much everything you need to run and support such a network. It's light years ahead of AWS.  They even have a full CI / CD pipepline that you could replicate for your own project. if you look at their marbles demo, you'll see what i mean.

Cello is definitely worth looking at, with the caveat that it's incubation meaning, not real yet, not production ready and not really useful until it becomes a fully fledged product.